# JMSSerializerBundle - preserve relation name

Tags: symfony, jmsserializerbundle

I'm using Symfony2 with JMSSerializerBundle. And I'm new with last one =) What should I do in such case:

I have Image model. It contains some fields, but the main one is "name". Also, I have some models, which has reference to Image model. For example User and Application. User model has OneToOne field "avatar", and Application has OneToOne field "icon". Now, I want to serialize User instance and get something like

```
{
     ...,
     "avatar": "http://example.com/my/image/path/image_name.png",
     ....
}
```

Also, I want to serialize Application and get

```
{
    ...,
    "icon": "http://example.com/my/image/path/another_image_name.png",
    ...
}
```

I'm using @Inline annotation on User::avatar and Application::icon fields to reduce Image object (related to this field) to single scalar value (only image "name" needed). Also, my Image model has ExclusionPolicy("all"), and exposes only "name" field. For now, JMSSerializer output is

```
(For User instance)
{
    ...,
    "name": "http://example.com/my/image/path/image_name.png",
    ...
}

(For Application instance)
{
    ...,
    "name": "http://example.com/my/image/path/another_image_name.png",
    ...
}
```

The question is: How can I make JMSSerializer to preserve "avatar" and "icon" keys in serialized array instead of "name"?

Comment: In any RESTful API you should always represent an object in the same way. If you have a relationship between User and Image, then the property "avatar" should be a scalar value, it should be the whole Image object serialised just as it would be anywhere else in the API. This creates greater consistency.

Comment: @JamesHalsall I agree with you, but I'm not able to change this decision =(

Comment: have you tried the `@SerializedName` property?

Comment: @JamesHalsall yes, it doesn't work with `@Inline`. `@Inline` uses related entity property name ("name" in example above).

Comment: how about adding an event listener for the `serializer.post_serialize` event?

Comment: @JamesHalsall solved this with combination of `@Type('Image')` and handler on type `Image`. In post_serialize event I can't remove or alter data, only add (https://github.com/schmittjoh/serializer/issues/74).

Comment: should add an answer and mark it resolved :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally, I found solution. In my opinion, it is not very elegant and beautiful, but it works.

1. I told to JMSSerializer, that User::avatar and Application::icon are Images. To do that, I used annotation `@Type("Image")`

   ```
   //src\AppBundle\Entity\User.php
   //...        
   /**
    * @var integer
    *
    * @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity="AppBundle\Entity\Image")
    * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="avatar", referencedColumnName="id")
    *
    * @JMS\Expose()
    * @JMS\Type("Image")
    */
   private $avatar;
   //...

   //src\AppBundle\Entity\Application.php
   //...
   /**
    * @var integer
    *
    * @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity="AppBundle\Entity\Image")
    * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="icon", referencedColumnName="id")
    *
    * @JMS\Expose()
    * @JMS\Type("Image")
    */
   private $icon;
   //...
   ```
2. I implemented handler, which serializes object with type `Image` to `json`.

   ```
   <?php
   //src\AppBundle\Serializer\ImageTypeHandler.php
   namespace AppBundle\Serializer;


   use AppBundle\Entity\Image;
   use JMS\Serializer\Context;
   use JMS\Serializer\GraphNavigator;
   use JMS\Serializer\Handler\SubscribingHandlerInterface;
   use JMS\Serializer\JsonSerializationVisitor;
   use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;

   class ImageTypeHandler implements SubscribingHandlerInterface
   {
       private $request;

       public function __construct(Request $request) {
           $this->request = $request;

       }

       static public function getSubscribingMethods()
       {
           return [
               [
                   'direction' => GraphNavigator::DIRECTION_SERIALIZATION,
                   'format' => 'json',
                   'type' => 'Image',
                   'method' => 'serializeImageToWebPath'
               ]
           ];
       }

       public function serializeImageToWebPath(JsonSerializationVisitor $visitor, Image $image = null, array $type, Context $context)
       {
           $path = $image ? "http://" . $this->request->getHost() . "/uploads/images/" . $image->getPath() : '';

           return $path;
       }
   }
   ```
3. And the last step is to register this handler. I also injected `request` service to generate full web path to image in my handler.

   ```
   app.image_type_handler:
       class: AppBundle\Serializer\ImageTypeHandler
       arguments: ["@request"]
       scope: request
       tags:
           - { name: jms_serializer.subscribing_handler }
   ```

Also, you can use [this](https://github.com/schmittjoh/serializer/issues/74) workaround, to modify serialized data in post_serialize event.